# How to decrease SKAction.rotateByAngle when sprite does full rotation (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So my question, which should be simple, if this sprite does a full rotation, how would I get it to decrease the duration by 0.5, or something of that nature?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Calibri")
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 65;
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    self.addChild(myLabel)

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:5)

    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

    self.addChild(sprite)
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to start off with a shorter duration or change duration after one rotation?

Comment: I want it to always start of at a set duration (5), and each time it rotates, it decreases the duration by 1, or 0.5 @Acey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sequence SKAction to queue a few actions together with the parameters you want. In your case, this might be a good start:

```
var actions = [SKAction]()

for var i = 5.0; i > 0; i -= 0.5 {
    actions.append(SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI), duration:i))
}

let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions)

sprite.runAction(sequence);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I get it to keep a certain duration when it reaches it's limit? Let's say duration is equal to 0.5, how do I get it to keep that duration 0.5 until the app stops? @Acey

Comment: Add another repeatActionForever action in the actions array like you already had above. actions.append(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 0.5))

Comment: A full rotation is 2.0*M_PI not M_PI.

Comment: Yes of course thanks @0x141E I just blindly copy pasta'd the above code. I'll make that update!